# How to combine multiple outputs in summarise in ddply in r?

Tags: r, plyr

For the `Orange` data frame why doesn't the following work?

```
library(plyr)

> ddply(Orange, .(Tree), summarise, circum = list(circumference))
Error: unsupported type for column 'circum' (VECSXP)
```

I want to combine all circumference values in 1 column.

### Orange data frame:

```
> dput(Orange)
structure(list(Tree = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("3", 
"1", "5", "2", "4"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), age = c(118, 
484, 664, 1004, 1231, 1372, 1582, 118, 484, 664, 1004, 1231, 
1372, 1582, 118, 484, 664, 1004, 1231, 1372, 1582, 118, 484, 
664, 1004, 1231, 1372, 1582, 118, 484, 664, 1004, 1231, 1372, 
1582), circumference = c(30, 58, 87, 115, 120, 142, 145, 33, 
69, 111, 156, 172, 203, 203, 30, 51, 75, 108, 115, 139, 140, 
32, 62, 112, 167, 179, 209, 214, 30, 49, 81, 125, 142, 174, 177
)), .Names = c("Tree", "age", "circumference"), row.names = c(NA, 
35L), class = c("nfnGroupedData", "nfGroupedData", "groupedData", 
"data.frame"), formula = circumference ~ age | Tree, labels = structure(list(
    x = "Time since December 31, 1968", y = "Trunk circumference"), .Names = c("x", 
"y")), units = structure(list(x = "(days)", y = "(mm)"), .Names = c("x", 
"y")))
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. My version is 1.8.1 on Mac.

Comment: @KFB `Orange` is attached.

Comment: Still no problem. May be you could retry loading the data `data(Orange)` and the latest `plyr`.  Or refresh R

Comment: It works after refreshing R. I think the problem occurs due to the use of `plyr` and `dplyr` simultaneously.